# Is there any advantage in using a DBaaS like mLab instead MongoDB locally?

Tags: database, mongodb, mlab, dbaas

I have mostly used mlab for small apps that i built while learning MEAN Stack, but not for any production level web app.

Answer (score 1):

DBaaS solutions take care of the complexities of managing a database so you don't have to worry about it.

There can be a lot to manage in a production database - configuration, backups, upgrades, monitoring, and more. It's possible to manage this yourself (and you'll learn a lot), but many developers choose to use a DBaaS so they can focus on developing their application.

Here are some examples of features a DBaaS might provide:

- **On-demand provisioning** - Highly-available and production-ready databases on the fly with a click of a button.
- **Upgrades** - Seamless upgrades of hardware as your data grows in size or of MongoDB versions as new versions are released with no downtime.
- **Backups** - A fully audited backup and recovery system so that you can recover data in case of an emergency. A robust backup system with frequent audits is critical for avoiding significant outages such as [the major outage that GitLab experienced](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/02/10/postmortem-of-database-outage-of-january-31/).
- **24x7 monitoring and alerting** - Tools that allow you to easily diagnose problems when your database is slow or if there are issues with the underlying VMs/network. Some providers might also take action on your behalf if a critical emergency occurs e.g. hardware failure/replacement.
- **Performance tuning** - Analytics tools that keep your database running smoothly. For example, mLab provides a Slow Query Analyzer for paid plans that continuously analyzes database server logs for slow operations and makes index and other performance recommendations.
- **Support** - An expert team to answer any questions about MongoDB - from architectural guidance to data modeling.

You might also find this article on [How to Choose a DBaaS](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-choose-a-dbaas) helpful.

*(Disclaimer: I work at mLab)*